Multiple line formula with two alignment points

How can I make this in LaTeX? So that both the words and the equality symbols are aligned, exactly like in the image

Welcome to TeX.SE.  We generally frown on questions that simply post an image and ask us to do everything.  Do you have an attempt of what you've done so far?

You can use the aligned environment:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\begin{aligned}
    &\text{If } & a+x&= a\\
    &\text{then } & (-a)+(a+x)&= (-a)+a=0;\\
    &\text{hence } & ((-a)+a)+x&=0;\\
    &\text{hence } & 0+x&=0;\\
    &\text{hence } & x&= 0.
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}


Does aligned add anything over align* in this case?

It gives the same thing, or almost. By default, align* centers the equation, while aligned treats it as "text". So since the set of equations is ragged left, I chose aligned.

You can use aligned or alignat, depending on how you want to control the spacing:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & \mathrm{If}           & a + x     &= a,       \\
    & \mathrm{then}         & (-a)+(a+x)&= (-a)+a=0;\\
    & \mathrm{hence}\quad   &((-a)+a)+x &= 0;       \\
    & \mathrm{hence}        & 0 + x     &= 0;       \\
    & \mathrm{hence}        & x         &= 0.
\end{alignat*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &\mathrm{If} & a+x&= a\\
    &\mathrm{then} & (-a)+(a+x)&= (-a)+a=0;\\
    &\mathrm{hence} & ((-a)+a)+x&=0;\\
    &\mathrm{hence} & 0+x&=0;\\
    &\mathrm{hence} & x&= 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}



I know the current answers already answer this question. But here it goes another option. This using an array environment.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{lrcl}
\text{If}    &        a+x & = & a,\\
\text{then}  & (-a)+(a+x) & = & (-a)+a=0;\\
\text{hence} & ((-a)+a)+x & = & 0;\\
\text{hence} &        0+x & = & 0;\\
\text{hence} &          x & = & 0.
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Make sure to replace \text with \rm in case that you do not want the text to match your current font style and want Roman for some reason. Hope it helps!

Edit: As suggested below, one should note that the lines are spaced more closely than in other environments. To control this (if you want to) you can add the desired line space after each linebreak, e.g. \\[1 ex]. My impression is that the array environment gives you more freedom, but this also comes with having to develop the skills to tailor it to suit your needs.

Note \rm is not defined by default in latex, and this produces unequal spacing around the = compare the two = on the second line

You should also mention (as a caveat for readers) that in an array environment, the material is typeset in text-style math mode instead of in display-style math mode and that the lines are spaced more closely than is the case in a usual multi-row math environment (such as align*).
